# PHP LDAP multiple context authentication

Tags: php, ldap

Good morning,

I have a php script that provides LDAP authentication (Code Below) however I need to authenticate to multiple contexts.

I was not sure of the best way to go about this and wondered if anyone might have any pointers/advice.

Kind regards,
Ben

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

//$ipaddressreceived = $_POST["ipaddress"];
$ldapcontext = "ou=Staff, ou=Users,o=ABC";
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("IPADDRESS");  // must be a valid LDAP server!
$ldaprdn = "cn=$username,$ldapcontext";

function authenticate($username, $password) {

        global $ldapconn;
        global $username;
        global $password;
        global $ldaprdn;
        // Prevent null binding
        if ($username === NULL || $password === NULL) { return false; } 
        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) { return false; }

        // Bind as the user        
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $password);;
        if ($ldapbind) { $ret = true;
        } else {
            $ret = false;
        }

        return $ret;
    }

$authUser=authenticate($username, $password);

if ($authUser == true) {


    session_start();
    $_SESSION["username"]=$username;

    $ldapfields = array("cn", "givenname", "sn", "mail");

    $ldapsearch=ldap_search($ldapconn, "$ldapcontext", "cn=$username", "$ldapfields");  
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $ldapsearch);

    $givenname =  $info["sn"][0];

    $_SESSION["givenname"]=$givenname;

    $login_message = "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL";

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;

    } else
    {
    $login_message = "Login Failed";

    }
```

Comment: Hi Darius, I have been trying to see whether it would work with a loop but couldn't get that working although I could have been going wrong somewhere. I haven't got the loop code that I had as I stripped it back to the working ldap code. My other thought was could an ldap search find a users context but wasn't sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

The naming contexts are published by the server in the Root DSE (although this information might be protected). Consider requesting the `namingContexts` multi-valued attribute from the Root DSE.

#### see also

- [The Root DSE](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/the-root-dse.html)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want to be able to authenticate `jondoe` from context `ou=Staff,ou=Users,o=ABC` as well as `janedoe` from context `ou=Externals,ou=Others,o=ABC`.

In my eyes there are two possible approaches as long as the usernames are unique acros the whole LDAP.

First you could add all possible contexts to an array `$contexts`and then loop through these contexts to find a matching user.

Second you use a two-stepped approach where you search for a user by its username in the whole LDAP and then use the returned `dn` to authenticate the user against the LDAP.

You can also combine the two approaches by giving more than one search-base and iterate over these in the step of searching for the users `dn`. As soon as you found a user, you can then authenticate it using the `dn` and the password.

You can find an example implementation at https://github.com/heiglandreas/authLdap/blob/master/ldap.php#L222.

Comment: Thank you, I will go and have a look at this today and come back.

Comment: I have tried getting the users dn by performing the ldap search but do not appear to be able to get a dn result. The code I am using is: $ldapsearch = ldap_search($ldapconn, "o=MCS", "cn=$username");     
$ldaprdn = ldap_get_dn($ldapconn, $ldapsearch);

Comment: Are you sure, that ```$username``` is actually stored in the field ```CN```? If you have the possibility to use the ```ldapsearch```-utility try to find your user with that. If you do not get a result, that could mean, that there is no match to your filter so you have to adapt your filter.

Comment: I modified my script a little to display the count of rows that it was returning and it was returning 1 row of data but for some reason if I ask it to dsiplay any of the data it doesn't display anything.  
`$attribs = array("cn", "sn", "givenname"); $ldapsearch=ldap_search($ldapconn, $ldapcontext, "cn=$username", $attribs); $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $ldapsearch); $ldapcount = " " .$info['count']. "entries returned" ; $cm=$info['cn'][0]; $sn=$info[$x]['sn'][0];`

Comment: ```$info[0]['dn']``` should contain your requested DN. Do you get anything sensible when ```var_dump```ing the content of ```$info```? - And what does ```echo ldap_count_entries($ldapconn, $ldapsearch)``` return?